# Python __init__ self attribute not available despite being printable

Tags: python

It worked fine all day suddenly it stopped.  I don't believe I changed the code at all maybe my brain stopped working???

```
class BorderWidgetWithLabel(BorderWidget): 

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(BorderWidgetWithLabel, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.text=" "
        self.text=kwargs.get('text',' ')
        print self.text
        self.txt_bg_color=kwargs.get("txt_bg_color", [0,0,0,0])
        self.bg_color=kwargs.get("bg_color", [0,0,0,0])

        self.bind(pos=self.update_canvas)
        self.bind(size=self.update_canvas)
        self.update_canvas()


    def update_canvas(self, *args):
        #need to reset everything
        self.canvas.clear()

        with self.canvas:

            get_color(self.border_color)
            if(self.text!=""):
                texture=simple_text_texture(self.text)
```

The problem:

```
/typeclasses/borderwidget.py", line 75, in update_canvas
if(self.text!=""):
AttributeError: 'BorderWidgetWithLabel' object has no attribute 'text'
```

I started getting that error I added `self.text=" "` in the `__init__` as well as the if statement in the update_canvas.  What am I doing wrong??

If I get rid of all the uses of self.text then the print self.text works no problem.

UPDATE:: Fixed by adding text=' ' as a class variable.  Is this necessary?? or is there something wrong with the code.  As print self.text in the **init** works fine without the class variable I am unable to provide a less complete sample

UPDATE:: I removed the self.update_canvas() last line of the **init** and it worked without the class variable but I attempted to reproduce that with the following

```
class SomeClass:
def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.text=kwargs.get("text","hello")
    self.update_class()


def update_class(self, *args):
    if(self.text!=' '):
        print self.text



SomeClass()
```

I don't know why I was unable to reproduce it then

Comment: Can you strip this down to a [mcve] that other people can run without having to have your `BorderWidget` class that still reproduces the problem? I can't see anything wrong here, and I even generated a mock `BorderWidget` and ran your code against it and I get no error.

Comment: I fixed it by adding text="" to the class as a class variable.  Is that needed??

Comment: since the print function works with no problem it is internal with one of the packages most likely being able to minimal or "complete" the question seems unlikely I can try

Comment: Adding `text` as a class variable should not help. It may _hide_ whatever problem you're having, but it won't _solve_ it. If the instance variable somehow gets deleted, you'll get the class variable—which will always be `' '` instead of the `text` argument from the initializer, which is useless.

Comment: Anyway, if you can't provide a more complete sample, there's no way anyone can help you. Unless there's an obvious typo or something that I missed that someone else can spot, there is just no way to debug code that we can neither read nor run.

Comment: I'm trying to get out of IDE and try a console short script that hopefully will reproduce the issue

Comment: You should also add the rest of your traceback, that is not the whole thing.

Comment: it failed I am unable to reproduce it without Kivy packages

Comment: Does `BorderWidget` call update_canvas() in its own __init__() method? I bet that is the problem...

Comment: That was the problem but I reproduced that same scenario and it didn't fail even on the if.  But that worked I took out the update_canvas

Comment: When python can't find an instance variable it looks for a like-named class variable. That's why it stops crashing when you add `text=''` to the class. But that's just masking the bug - the instance variable should be there. @PaulBecotte has a great guess for why that's happening. Put `self.text = kwargs.get(...)` _before_ the `__init__` to see if that fixes. A full stack trace would show it also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it looks like you have

```
class BW:
  def __init__(self):
    self.update_canvas()

  def update_canvas(self):
    pass

class BWL(BW):
  def __init__(self):
    super(BWL, self).__init__()
    self.text = 'text'
    self.update_canvas()

  def update_canvas(self):
    print self.text
```

Running `BWL()` would throw the exception you listed. This is because the order of events is

1. call BWL.init
2. which calls BW.init (with self = BWL)
3. which calls self.update_canvas (which is BWL.update_canvas)
4. which accesses self.text
5. Then, when BW.init returns, it creates self.text
6. and finally calls self.update_canvas again.

This is probably not what you want even without the bug... probably remove the call to super or the call to update_canvas in the child, and set up the properties you need in the update_canvas method BEFORE calling the super class.

Comment: It was the parent class class causing the problem?  Thank you for your time I had no idea why everything was working and then suddenly came crashing to a halt.  THANK YOU!